# React-table MUI Menu on the end of every row

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-table

I'm trying to make a exapnding action button with MUI Menu, but unfortunately it throws me an error like as below:

> react_devtools_backend.js:2655 Warning: findDOMNode is deprecated in
> StrictMode. findDOMNode was passed an instance of Transition2 which is
> inside StrictMode. Instead, add a ref directly to the element you want
> to reference.

Is there any solution for this problem expected get rid of `Strict Mode`?

```js
import MoreVertIcon from '@mui/icons-material/MoreVert';
import { IconButton, Menu, MenuItem } from '@material-ui/core';
import React, { useState, useMemo } from 'react';
import { useTable } from 'react-table';
import { ContentWrapper } from '~/components/Content/ContentWrapper';
import { DataGrid } from '~/components/Table/Table';

const Example = () => {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState(null);
  const columns = useMemo(() => COLUMNS, []);
  const data = useMemo(() => MOCK_DATA, []);

  const tableInstance = useTable(
    {
      columns,
      data,
    },
    hooks => {
      hooks.visibleColumns.push(columns => [
        ...columns,
        {
          id: 'actions',
          Cell: () => {
            return (
              <TableActionButton
                setAnchorEl={setAnchorEl}
                anchorEl={anchorEl}
              />
            );
          },
        },
      ]);
    },
  );

  return (
    <ContentWrapper>
      <DataGrid tableInstance={tableInstance} />
    </ContentWrapper>
  );
};

const TableActionButton = ({ setAnchorEl, anchorEl }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <IconButton onClick={e => setAnchorEl(e.currentTarget)}>
        <MoreVertIcon />
      </IconButton>
      <Menu
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
        onClose={() => setAnchorEl(null)}>
        <MenuItem>Profile</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem>My account</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem>Logout</MenuItem>
      </Menu>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: I think that error is pretty good. Just follow the error. use `ref` hook like this `<Menu
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
        onClose={() => setAnchorEl(null)}
        ref={menuRef}
      >`

Comment: In index.js under the root folder, change `<React.StrictMode><App /><React.StrictMode>` to `<App />`, more about the context, refer to https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html